# Best way to manage button click via jquery

Tags: jquery, events, button, click

in my jquery web application, i need to manage several kinds of button. All buttons have ui-button css'class, and a specific css class for spefic button's action, for example

```
<div class="ui-button">
    Google
</div>
<div class="ui-button ui-button-search">
    Search
</div>
<div class="ui-button ui-button-submit">
    Submit
</div>
<div class="ui-button ui-button-action1">
    Action1
</div>
<div class="ui-button ui-button-action2">
    Action2
</div>
```

So, i need to attach jquery handler to manage button's action. For example,

- if user clicks on div.ui-button without other css classes, browser goes to www.google.it
- if user clicks on div.ui-button.ui-search, browser opens a dialog for text input
- if user clicks on div.ui-button.ui-submit, browser submits button's parent form
- if user clicks on div.ui-button.ui-actionX, browser performs actionX.

So, can you give me an idea on how to attach events to buttons without conflicts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best would be to add ui-button-google, then you can cleanly bind to all buttons individually.

jQuery 1.7 introduces on/off so all you need to do is target each one:

`$('.TARGET-CLASS').on('click', function() {})`

If you don't add the class to the Google button, you can alternatively bind to the general UI button and do a check for classes present on the button.

```
$('.ui-button').on('click', function(){
  if $(this).hasClass('ui-button-search'){
    //search 
  }
  else if $(this).hasClass('ui-button-submit') {
    //submit
  }
...
  else {
    //google
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just attach click handlers by CSS class. You'd need to add a class to the first case though (going to google.it), or additional code to check that it's the only class present before proceeding.

```
$('.ui-button-search').click(function () { open your dialog for text input here });
$('.ui-button-submit').click(function () { submit the parent form (you can get it with this.parents('form') } );
$('.ui-button-action1').click(function () { perform action #1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.ui-button').click(function() {
    var classAr = $(this).attr('class').match(/\sui-\w+-\w+\s*/gi);
    var uiClass = classAr[0].replace(/\s*/g,'');
    switch (uiClass) {
       case 'ui-button-search':
         //some instructions
     break;
       case 'ui-button-submit':
         //some instructions
     break;
default:
    //some instructions
        break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try something like this:

```
$('div.ui-button')
    .click(function() {
        // google it
    })
    .filter('.ui-button-search')
    .unbind('click')
    .click(function() {
        // open dialog for text input
    })
    .end()
    .filter('.ui-button-submit')
    .unbind('click')
    .click(function() {
        // submit
    })
    .end()
    .filter('.ui-button-action1')
    .unbind('click')
    .click(function() {
        // action1
    });
```

Edit:

Need to put `.unbind()` to this code works, making it a bad solution. =/

Comment: @Jared Sorry, that's true. In my solution will need to use unbind('click')

Comment: Unbind won't fix the issue though... all buttons respond to the selector 'div.ui-button' and thusly will run the google function first. But I like the approach :)